# Play different audio files based on data-type

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to modify this game [this](http://thewebrocks.com/demos/html5catcher/). I did everything I wanted except one thing:
when player cathes "good" data-type I want sound 1.mp3 is played. When bad - sound 2.mp3.

I added in html file:

```
<audio id="goodsound" source src="sounds/1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="badsound" source src="sounds/2.mp3"></audio>
```

and added vars in js file:

```
  love = $( '#goodsound' ),
  hate = $( '#badsound' ),
```

But i can't understand where play.goodsound(); need to be placed. Sorry if it is foolish question, I am only learning js and trying to solve this question for second day. Thanks for your help!

P.S. Source of js file is [here](http://thewebrocks.com/demos/html5catcher/js/game.js).

Comment: Got more of your changes to the code to show? It can be something like this `var sound = document.getElementById("goodsound"); sound.play();`

Comment: There are no changes in js file for now except this 2 strings I wrote earlier. I tried to add  here: `if ( ~~(score/newsprite) > levelincrease ) {
      love.play(); sprites.push( addsprite() );
      levelincrease++;
    }` but it only play sound on level up, not when catching objects.

Comment: Have you defined `love` anywhere?

Comment: yes, https://pastebin.com/V1EG18AJ here what I've got for now: sounds play on level up and gameover. But the question is how to make them play when i catch good/bad objects?

Comment: yes, in html file - <audio id="nice" source src="sounds/nice.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="bad" source src="sounds/bad.mp3"></audio>.  And then I just use love.play() and hate.play().

Comment: The score is updated in `function sprite() {` , so you'll need to play the sounds in there.

Comment: Thanks! Added code here and works perfectly: `while ( i-- ) {
            scores[ this.effects[ i ].effect ] += +this.effects[ i ].value;
   omnom.play();
          }`